# Proposed tag: sdcard

Tags: feature-request, tags

We have a tag for [hard-drive](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-drive) but nothing for "storage" or "sdcard".  Adding this tag should make it easier for folks to find questions similar to the one they're asking which will hopefully reduce duplicates or make them easier to find.  Given that we have [228 results for "sd card"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=sd+card) it seems like there is enough critical mass for this tag.

I also considered tags like "capacity" or "specifications" which we don't have, but making it more specific and real world seems like it would be more likely for folks to find and use it easily.

Comment: Anyone above a certain reputation can create tags as needed. If it doesn't exist, it's probably not needed.

Comment: How can someone be an expert in "specifications"?

Comment: Yet we get questions about console specifications such as http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/306474/what-is-the-highest-supported-micro-sd-capacity-for-the-nintendo-switch/306475#306475

Comment: I don't see the point in having this tag.  Usually, the question title or body clarifies what a user is looking for.  This tag probably wouldn't help much.  IMO, the hard drive tag is probably not needed either.  Someone could always make it, but tags get auto deleted if there aren't any posts that use them after a certain amount of time.

Comment: Of those 228 results, [only 87 are questions](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?page=1&tab=relevance&pagesize=50&q=sd+card+is%3aq). Secondly, there isn't a whole lot of difference between storage mediums from a gamer's perspective, any differentiated knowledge of the storage medium is usually discussed in the context of the device in question (be it PC/home consoles for hard drives/ssds or a specific handheld device for SD cards).

Comment: Also we tend to favour a breadth-first tag system wherein we have a bunch of 'small' tags (usually individual games or consoles) rather than overarching 'topic area' tags like [specifications] (there are exceptions, like [achievements] but they are few and far between).

Answer (score 1):

I would propose the creation of a tag called [additional-storage](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/additional-storage), that both [hard-drive](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-drive) and [sd-card](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sd-card) would point to. (We can do that right?)

I do think there's a demand, because SD cards being bigger and bigger, hard drives will probably lose their place for SD Cards.